# BTRFS RAID 0 and Linux reinstallation

Tags: btrfs

In case I add two drives (non-system drives) in RAID 0 using btrfs, what would happen if I need to re-install the operating system, would this RAID 0 be gone and data lost?

Answer (score 0):

The File System and all the metadata lives on the disk. That means, as long as you don't reformat the drive it should be possible to reinstall your operating system.

Depending on your actual configuration you may have separate subvolumes for `/`, `/home`, `/var` etc. You can reinstall your operating system by wiping the respective subvolumes (i.e. `/`) and then installing your os into newly created subvolumes.